Populate cells until a target is met or no remaining number
Apologies the title is rather vague, as it is hard to sumarise the problem in a short sentence.
Here is an example of an input with the desired output:



Flow

April 2024
------------




Incoming

100



Outgoing 1

23.2



Outgoing 2

10



Remainder

66.8



------------
--------
------------



Name
Target
Actual
Projected


------------
--------
------------
-----------


Sample1
100
99
100


Sample2
100
110
110


Sample3
80
80
80


Sample4
10
0
10


Sample5
10
0
10


Sample6
10
0
10


Sample7
100
101
101


Sample8
100
92.2
100


Sample9
62.8
63
63


Sample10
10
10
10


Sample11
10
9
10


Sample12
5
5
5


Sample13
Left
136.12
163.12



In this example. The "Remainder" will fill the accounts in "Projected", up until the target is reached (getting the difference from Actual). (Note, if the actual is greater than the target, then nothing happens).
It will then continue to populate down, until there is the "Remainder" has been depleted.
In this example, the remainder is 66.8.
Meaning the following is added into each "Projected" on top of the "Actual":

Sample1: 1
Sample2: 0
Sample3: 0
Sample4: 10
Sample5: 10
Sample6: 10
Sample7: 0
Sample8: 7.8
Sample9: 0
Sample10: 0
Sample11: 1
Sample12: 0
Sample13: 27
Total: 66.8

The final "Sample 13", will take the final remainder, there is no target for this.
Here is another example if the remainder is a small number that wont fill all accounts:



Flow

April 2024
------------




Incoming

100



Outgoing 1

23.2



Outgoing 2

75.8



Remainder

1



------------
-----------
------------



Name
Target
Actual
Projected


------------
-----------
------------
-----------


Sample1
100
99
100


Sample2
100
110
110


Sample3
80
80
80


Sample4
10
0
0


Sample5
10
0
0


Sample6
10
0
0


Sample7
100
101
101


Sample8
100
92.2
92.2


Sample9
62.8
63
63


Sample10
10
10
10


Sample11
10
9
9


Sample12
5
5
5


Sample13
Remainder
136.12
136.12



The amount of "Sample" could grow or shrink
I made a EXAMPLE_SHEET so it may be easier to understand


Here's one approach you may test out:
=choosecols(scan({0,0},L8:index(L:L,match(,0/(L:L="Remainder"))),lambda(a,c,let(Σ,offset(c,,1),Λ,if(+a<>"",+a+if(c-Σ>0,c-Σ,),),
  if(and(c="Remainder",+a<>""),{"",Σ+M5-+a},
  if(isbetween(M5,+a,Λ),{"",Σ+M5-+a},
  if(+a<M5,{Λ,max(c,Σ)},{"",Σ})))))),2)



Hey mate, I added another use case where this did not work for in the attached google sheet

Test the updated solution
